# GWT track modification on a set of input widgets

Tags: gwt, event-handling, widget

I have an application where the user can modify an entity, say customer, by modifying a bunch of text-boxes, list-boxes, date-pickers and check-boxes. I also have 2 buttons, save and cancel. I would like to enable the save button if an actual change was made (i.e. one of the input widgets has been modified). Obviously, this can be done in a "brute-force" way by manually adding a change listener to every widget. Or a slight improvement could be to define lists of widgets and add listeners in a for loop.
I am curious whether anyone has a more elegant solution?

Thanks,
Matyas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use UiBinder you can use something like:

```
@UiField TextBox textBoxA;
@UiField TextBox textBoxB;
@UiField TextBox textBoxC;
@UiField DatePicker datPickerA;
@UiField RadioButton radioButton;

...

@UiHandler(value={"textBoxA", "textBoxB", "textBoxC", "datePickerA"})
void somethingChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
  // Enable your save button.
}

@UiHandler("radioButton")
void somethingClicked(ClickEvent e) {
  // Enable your save button.
}
```

Comment: When applying for a RadioButton, GWT throws the following error: Field 'personType' does not have an 'addChangeHandler' method associated.

Comment: For `radio buttons` (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RadioButton.html) you can use ClickEvent